# Batch file to telnet and run commands on a unix server

Tags: file, unix, batch-file, telnet

I'm stuck here, and I really can use your help. Here's my situation.

Im looking forward to create a batch script which can access a unix server using telnet. Here the unix sever will ask for username/password. After it has authenticated the user, i want to preform some operations like chown on a perticular file.

Here's what im looking to do :

```
    telnet
    open xyz.abc.com
    username
    password

    command 1
    command 2
    command 3
    exit
```

where

```
xyz.abc.com is the unix server where i want to connect.
username and password are the credentials to access this server 
command 1,command 2,command 3 are the commands i want to run in the server.
```

My problem is i cant use SSH.
It should take all the data from the file instead of prompting the user to enter data and should run as an automated script.

Answer (score 2):

This is the .bat file I created to telnet to a server, change a file permission, then ftp the file to my PC and open it. Hopefully it will help you out. The variable filename is there because I always login and move to the same directory name every time. You can change it to a prompt so the user can enter where they would like to cd to. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
:: This will telnet to the server, change the permissions, 
:: download the file, and then open it from your PC. 

:: Add your username, password, servername, and file path to the file.
:: I have not tested the server name with an IP address.

:: Note - telnetcmd.dat and ftpcmd.dat are temp files used to hold commands

@echo off
SET username=
SET password=
SET servername=
SET filepath=

set /p id="Enter the file name: " %=%

echo user %username%> telnetcmd.dat
echo %password%>> telnetcmd.dat
echo cd %filepath%>> telnetcmd.dat
echo SITE chmod 777 %id%>> telnetcmd.dat
echo exit>> telnetcmd.dat
telnet %servername% < telnetcmd.dat


echo user %username%> ftpcmd.dat
echo %password%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd %filepath%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo get %id%>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat %servername%

SET mypath=%~dp0
%mypath%%id%

del ftpcmd.dat
del telnetcmd.dat
```

Comment: Since he stated "create a batch script which can access a unix server using telnet" I assumed that he was running this from a windows PC and needed to access a unix server.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). Thie above is exactly what it's designed for.

> Expect is a Unix automation and testing tool, written by Don Libes as
>   an extension to the Tcl scripting language, for interactive
>   applications such as telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, ssh, and
>   others. It uses Unix pseudo terminals to wrap up subprocesses
>   transparently, allowing the automation of arbitrary applications that
>   are accessed over a terminal.

Comment: Thanks Brain, My problem is ill later be using this to call from Java application. anyway i can do it simply by using batch programming or something on the same grounds.