# how to use a batfch file to log in to a router and then send commands to the router

Tags: windows, batch-file, telnet, router

I am attempting to write a batch file to open a telnet session , connect to router ,enter username and password and finally send a command to the router, I have two different routers I am attempting this with . one of them a netgear i can successfully unlock telnet on the router (it is locked by default and once unlocked ,reverts after reboot) open telnet session and connect to the router.to unlock telnet i have a program telnetenable.exe which is stored in c:/

```
echo off
echo c:/telnetenable.exe ipaddress username password
telnet ipaddress
```

but cant send a command to the router once at this point ,at which i have an open connection to the router and can enter cmd manually which is adslctl configure --snr x
but i would like to incorporate it into the batch file.

on the second router a speedstream 4200 telnet is not locked and i can open the telnet session and connect to router but cant enter username or password after which i want to be able to send a cmd.

```
echo off
telnet ipaddress
```

gets me as far as username request. can anyone help me with either of these problems.
many thanks.

Comment: windows telnet is a very basic/braindead program and doesn't have scripting support. you need something more robust that can accept input from a file, which is where you'd list your "input" (e.g. usernames/passwords, commands, etc...)

Comment: thanks for your reply , i came across this, I cant understand the instructions but thought that although not exactly what  i wanted it was possible?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626071/batch-file-to-telnet-and-run-commands-on-a-unix-server

Answer (score 0):

Search for this free tool.  Windows telnet can't be scripted.

```
Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0 by Albert Yale
```