# Login via dos to my router

Tags: batch-file

I would like to do a batch file.
This file will have to do these things:

1. Connect to a specific page of my router ( using telnet function )
2. Telnet to my router
3. Set the snr

Obviously automatically, without my action for login or something else.

For the first point I use the start command to open the page on my browser, but I have no idea how to login into this page. Is this possible?

Comment: Yeah sorry, i'm talking about the command prompt, i've made a mistake

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post code, if you have it.  Also, have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887976/how-to-use-a-batfch-file-to-log-in-to-a-router-and-then-send-commands-to-the-rou

Comment: Yeah, this is the actually code: 

start http://192.168.0.1/setup.cgi?todo=debug
pause
telnet 192.168.0.1

Now i'll look to the link